# What is the following known as?

Tags: algorithm

I have a simple algorithmic problem.

- I have a set of positive integers `S` and a positive maximum integer `i`.
- Let's say the sum of `S` (or a subset of `S`) is the sum of its elements.
- I need to find a subset `s` of `S` whose sum does not exceed `i` and is "maximally summing" - meaning no other subset of `S` has a greater sum than `s` without exceeding `i`.

The trivial solution I came up with is to go over each set of the power set of `S` and sum the integers, keeping track of the set with the properties I seek, but this algorithm is obviously exponential.

There must be a well-known name for this problem, as I don't think I am the first to come across this need. Could someone help me out?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: One approach to solve the "Knapsack problem" would be dynamic programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: @user2357112 You should convert that to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solve subset sum problem for your set using dynamic programming.

Then scan filled table from i-th entry to smaller values until you find non-zero entry (i.e. such sum exists). This is the largest sum of subsets that not exceeding given value.